# solution to inverse trig function, decimals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question asks for no decimals, but I end up with a solution that contains a decimal, what am I doing wrong?

$$6cos^2(\frac{x}{2}) - 7cos(\frac{x}{2})+2=0 \text{ ; }{\forall x \in \mathbb{R}} \text{  ; NO DECIMALS}$$
$$(3cos(\frac{x}{2}) - 2)(2cos(\frac{x}{2})-1)=0$$
$${cos(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{2}{3}}\text{ , }{cos(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$cos^-1(\frac{1}{2})= \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$cos^-1(\frac{2}{3})=0.841068671$$
$$\frac{\pi}{3} * 2 = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
$$0.841068671*2 = 1.682137342$$
$$x = \frac{2\pi}{3} + 4\pi k \text{ , k any integer }$$
$$x = 1.682137342 + 4\pi k \text{ , k any integer }$$

is the four pi period correct?

Comment: You mean to say that it intends for you to express $x$ without decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expressing the answer in terms of decimals. It intends for you to leave your answer in terms of pi.

$x$ over the interval $[−\infty, \infty]$ satisfies $6\cos^2(x2)−7\cos(x2)+2=0$ for values $x=\frac2{3}(6\pi k\pm \pi)$ and $x = 2(2\pi k\pm\arccos(\frac2{3}))$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: yes but, if the answer is correct, how can I express that decimal in terms of pi without decimals?

Comment: @hit Well, for what you've given--that $x=2\pi/3+4\pi k$ when $k = \Bbb Z$ (any integer). You may then express that in a given set, say—arbitrarily, $[-\pi, \pi]$ (denoting the set of values $x$ between the interval $x = -\pi$ and $x = \pi$). So you then give the values of that set which satisfy the conditions of $x$ (with values of $k$, and therefore values of $x$, for example: in the set $[-\pi, \pi]$, $x = 2\pi/3$.

Comment: @hit does that answer your question better?

Comment: sort-of, but, the domain of x is. for all x in real numbers, not between [-pi, pi]. unless that's the only way to express the answer? but I could be just doing the problem wrong, idk

Comment: @hit So your interval is then $[-\infty, \infty]$, and your solution would be: $x$ over the interval $[-\infty, \infty]$ satisfies $6\cos^2(x2)−7cos(x2)+2=0$ for values  $x = \frac{2\pi}{3} + 4\pi k$ for $k = \Bbb Z$. Does this clarify your question, and is all the notation understandable as well?

Comment: @hit If this clears up all your confusion, accepting my answer and closing the topic would be nice (and maybe a +1 on my answer if you liked it c:). I made a slight error, interval notation for that set should be $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: but what about the other answer? do I just exclude it because it is a decimal? it doesn't seem like the right way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14446/discussion-between-alx-and-hit)